# How to Shortly Reset a XML File and Saved Class To Create A New Game - in UNITY

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

for my unity game: How can I reset a xml file and its saved class variables to create a new game?

I want all the saved data to be reset.

DO i have to manually reset all the class variables by code; such as healthPoints = 100, collectedStars = 0... etc etc

OR is there a shortcut to reset a class's variables and delete old xml file from its path?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how any xml file comes into play here, but the usual way to restart/reset a game in Unity is to either reload the same scene ( https://answers.unity.com/questions/1311254/restart-whole-scene.html ) or switch to a different "scene" (which can show a nice game-over or scores display etc.) and then return to the game scene.

That recreates all objects with their initial values.

If you want to keep an object across multiple scenes (like an object that keeps track of highscores) you have to explicitly set is at "DontDestroyOnLoad": https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html